# XMLReader and XSSFSheetXMLHandler start parsing worksheet from second row (java, poi)

Tags: java, apache-poi, sax, xmlreader

I am using streaming & SAX Parsing technic (described in many posts) to process .xlsx file. It works fine on sample files, processing each worksheets from very first row. But I got an Excel file from the business users with production data, for that the processing starts from the row 2 (instead of 1, skipping header). What kind of settings on the file may cause this behavior? Or what can I do in code to force parsing from the row I want?
I am using poi 3.9

Snapshots of the code:

```
protected void processSheet(StylesTable styles, ReadOnlySharedStringsTable strings, InputStream sheetInputStream) throws IOException, SAXException {

        InputSource sheetSource = new InputSource(sheetInputStream);
        SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser saxParser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader sheetParser = saxParser.getXMLReader();
            ContentHandler handler = new XSSFSheetXMLHandler(styles, strings, new MySheetParser(),false);
            sheetParser.setContentHandler(handler);
            sheetParser.parse(sheetSource);

// ...

public class MySheetParser implements SheetContentsHandler
```

Comment: Revise your embed source code, then format it carefully!

Comment: Upgrade to a significantly more recent version of Apache POI, complete with lots of bug fixes?